# Passing props React (Typescript) .Net core

Tags: reactjs, typescript, .net-core, http-put

Im trying to pass an Id (could be seen as a state i guess) from a component to another

In component Home:

```
interface FetchDataExampleState {
    games: Games[];
    loading: boolean;
}
interface Games {
    g_Id: number;
    g_Title: string;
    g_Genre: string;
    g_Plattform: string;
    g_ReleaseDate: Date;
    g_Price: number;
}
```

i got the 2 Interfaces from which i want to pass the g_Id to use in in EditGame

My Put API:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [Route("EditGame")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutGame([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Game game)
    {

        game.G_Id = id;

        _context.Entry(game).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!GameExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

The fetch im Trying to use in the EditGame component :

```
handleClick = (e: any) => {
    console.log("Hello");
    fetch("api/Games/EditGame", {
        method: 'PUT', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({
            g_Title: this.state.g_Title,
            g_Genre: this.state.g_Genre,
            g_Plattform: this.state.g_Plattform,
            g_ReleaseDate: this.state.g_ReleaseDate,
            g_Price: this.state.g_Price,
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            this.setState({
                g_Title: data.g_Title,
                g_Genre: data.g_Genre,
                g_Plattform: data.g_Plattform,
                g_ReleaseDate: data.g_ReleaseDate,
                g_Price: data.g_Price,
            });
            let path = '/Home';
            this.props.history.push(path);
        });
}
```

My Routes :

```
<Route path='/Home' component={Home} />
<Route path='/EditGame' component={EditGame} />
```

I tried looking it up and tried all the Top results including:

1. [Github](https://gist.github.com/kvendrik/fc859b96ecc6fb9faf5c28cabcd7f254)
2. [How to pass props to route in react router v5 with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651500/how-to-pass-props-to-route-in-react-router-v5-with-typescript)
3. [Pass component props in Private Route with Typescript and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63463502/pass-component-props-in-private-route-with-typescript-and-react)
4. [Pass props through react router link typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307737/pass-props-through-react-router-link-typescript)

I'm not sure if im missing something since i'm new to react or if i'm doing something wrong.
Thanks for the Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time of searching i was able to solve it as following

```
<li><Link to={{ pathname: "/EditGame", state: { id: games.g_Id, title: games.g_Title, genre: games.g_Genre, Plattform: games.g_Plattform, rdate: games.g_ReleaseDate, price: games.g_Price } }} >Edit</Link></li>
```

by calling the values from home and passing them through state to EditGame where i called them like this in the fitch method

```
 handleClick = (e: any) => {
        console.log("Hello");
        fetch("api/Games/EditGame", {
            method: 'PUT' + this.props.location.state.id, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, body: JSON.stringify({
                g_Id: this.props.location.state.id,
                g_Title: this.props.location.state.title,
                g_Genre: this.props.location.state.genre,
                g_Plattform: this.props.location.state.Plattform,
                g_ReleaseDate: this.props.location.state.rdate,
                g_Price: this.props.location.state.price,
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({
                    g_Title: data.g_Title,
                    g_Genre: data.g_Genre,
                    g_Plattform: data.g_Plattform,
                    g_ReleaseDate: data.g_ReleaseDate,
                    g_Price: data.g_Price,
                });
                let path = '/Home';
                this.props.history.push(path);
            });
    }
```

now it might not be the best way, but it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

try to use React Functional Component

or more like this base on my experience.

```
<Route path='/EditGame/:id' component={EditGame} />
```

props.match.params.id

Comment: Could you maybe tell me please what i should exactly do with the "props.match.params.id"  i don't think just adding "Route path='/EditGame/:id' component={EditGame} />" would do the trick, since the id is from home and should be sent to EditGame